# Fixing improperly patched and painted stucco?

Tags: painting, stucco

I just had my stucco home painted. There were some cracks in the stucco that the painters patched before painting. After painting, the patched areas look extremely obvious, like lines and blotches all over the wall.

What did the painters do wrong and how can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: are you sure it was painted

Comment: wrong trowel used,

Comment: Yes, it was definitely painted and they tried multiple coats to hide the patches, but this is the result.

Comment: Do you know *how* they patches the areas? What products were used?